# "Both the earth and the moon do not shine by their own light[s]"

Tags: grammatical-number

> Both the earth and the moon do not shine by their own light/lights.

Which is grammatical, the singular, the plural, or both?

Comment: It would be more idiomatic to negate *both* rather than *shine* - ***Neither** the earth **nor** the moon shine by their own light*. But if they did, idiomatically [*they shine by their own **light***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22they+shine+by+their+own+light%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) (singular gets 48 hits in Google Books there, but the plural returns no hits at all).

Comment: You need to capitalize *Earth* and *Moon*. The earth without a capital E is the soil under your feet. Which does not shine, ever, except perhaps as radioactive soil in some cartoon.

Comment: Although with neither/nor, it would be "... shines by its own light."

Comment: Either is fine.  You're drifting out into poetic style issues, and so long as there's no egregious syntax error you're pretty free to pick and choose.  (The distinction is whether "light" is being treated as countable or uncountable, and that's up to the author to decide.)

Comment: ... although the usual idiom is 'by its/their own light' (ie a noncount usage within a fixed expression). Compare 'Potatoes are sold by weight' (not weights).

Answer (score 1):

Use the singular, because you began with "Both" and identified each singular item you are describing.  Also capitalize, as RegDwight posted.

Answer (score 1):

I also would prefer the neither/nor construction suggested by FumbleFingers in his comment.  But if that weren't an alternative, I would probably use "light" rather than "lights".  My rationale is that light, at least when used in this sense, is an **uncountable** noun.  "Uncountable" is defined by Wiktionary as:

> A noun that cannot be used freely with numbers or the indefinite
>   article, and which therefore takes no plural form.

We can perhaps make this more clear by keeping the same sentence structure, but substituting some words:

> Both Adam and Betty feast on their own butter.